# Inner working of fillna() when used with groupby and transform

Tags: python, pandas, transform, pandas-groupby, fillna

I am trying to learn ML by solving the Titanic ML problem at kaggle and there are many `Age` values that are missing. I am following a tutorial to solve the problem.

if I use

```
median_age = df.groupby('Title')['Age'].transform('median')
```

then it gives me something like

```
>>>median_age.sample(12)

PassengerId
1053     4.0
891     29.0
524     35.0
570     29.0
1236     4.0
463     29.0
359     22.0
403     22.0
604     29.0
791     29.0
512     29.0
1290    29.0
Name: Age, dtype: float64
```

These are the `median ages` respective to each category of `Title`

My question is -

**If I use** `df['Age'].fillna(median_age, inplace=True)` **, How is it filling the values? What is the inner working of this last line?**

Comment: `df['Age'].fillna(median_age, inplace=True)` finds median for whole `Age` column and put this value into NaNs in this column.

Comment: How does it know the ```Age``` category and what to fill in each ```NaN``` as ```median_age```is just a ```Series```?

Comment: @Deshwal - it woriking nice because same index of `df` and `median_age`, also same length, so matching nice.

Comment: okay so it goes to some index where there are ```NaN``` and it maps using the ```PassangerID```? Means whatever value of ```Age``` is presented there, it just copies the value in place of ```NaN```?

Comment: yes, exactly.  it just copies the value in place of NaN.